# Online Taylor series calculator

Tags: reference-request

When I compute the the eigenvalues of the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}x^3& 2 + x^3& 3 - 2 x^3\\ 2 + x^3& 4 - 5 x^3& 5 + 3 x^3\\ 3 - 2 x^3& 5 + 3 x^3& x^3\end{bmatrix}$$ using WolframAlpha, I get the following first eigenvalue (copied from WolframAlpha):

```
λ_1 = 1/3 (4 - 3 x^3) + 1/3 (-432 x^9 - 1449 x^6 + 810 x^3 + 3 sqrt(3) sqrt(-10664 x^18 + 34200 x^15 - 38845 x^12 - 162020 x^9 - 241908 x^6 + 30520 x^3 - 38808) + 1072)^(1/3) - (-78 x^6 - 18 x^3 - 130)/(3 (-432 x^9 - 1449 x^6 + 810 x^3 + 3 sqrt(3) sqrt(-10664 x^18 + 34200 x^15 - 38845 x^12 - 162020 x^9 - 241908 x^6 + 30520 x^3 - 38808) + 1072)^(1/3))
```

I want to see the first few terms of the Taylor expansion around x=0 of that expression, however, it seems WolframAlpha cannot handle it. I have been looking for an online Taylor series calculator that can do this but it seems the expression is too hard to crack.

**Question:** Can anyone share with me a website where I can compute the first few terms (until $x^3$) of the desired Tylor expansion about $x=0$? I do not know how to use programs like Matlab to do this. Do you have any recommendations?

In case it is of any help, here is the expression:
$$  \frac{1}{3} (4 - 3 x^3) + \frac{1}{3} (-432 x^9 - 1449 x^6 + 810 x^3 + 3 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{-10664 x^{18} + 34200 x^{15} - 38845 x^{12} - 162020 x^9 - 241908 x^6 + 30520 x^3 - 38808} + 1072)^{1/3} - \frac{(-78 x^6 - 18 x^3 - 130)}{(3 (-432 x^9 - 1449 x^6 + 810 x^3 + 3 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{-10664 x^{18} + 34200 x^{15} - 38845 x^{12} - 162020 x^9 - 241908 x^6 + 30520 x^3 - 38808} + 1072)^{1/3})}$$

Comment: I don't know of an online tool, but Maxima, which is open source, didn't have a problem with it. See https://maxima.sourceforge.io/

Comment: Try sage, a free software computer algebra system.

Comment: Is this really a question suitable for CS.SE?

Comment: Hi @Juho. Do you know a better place to ask this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SageMath](https://www.sagemath.org/) can compute Taylor series. It is free software that can be downloaded for free, or it can be used online via [CoCalc](https://cocalc.com/).

The following code will calculate Taylor series for all three eigenvalues:

```
M = matrix([[x^3, 2+x^3, 3-2*x^3], [2+x^3, 4-5*x^3, 5+3*x^3], [3-2*x^3, 5+3*x^3, x^3]])     
[taylor(lam,x,0,3) for lam in M.eigenvalues()]
```

The resulting expressions don't seem too useful. In particular, although the eigenvalues are real, the equations involve complex numbers (possibly an example of [casus irreducibilis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis)).

Comment: That's great! Could you please explain what lam is? I would like to understand how the second line of the code works. What does 0 and 3 stand for in taylor(lam,x,0,3)? Thanks.